# Polynomial in $z$ not bounded on $\mathbb{C}^-$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

This is part of a proof that shows that explicit Runge-Kutta-methods are not A-stable. It states the following:
Given we have a polynomial $R(z)\in P_s$ in $z$  of degree at most $s\geq p>0$, then $R(z)$ is not bound on the set
$$
\mathbb{C}^-:= \{z\in \mathbb{C}: Re(z)\leq0 \}
$$
This was stated without a proof or explanation and is the only part in the proof I am struggeling with, so I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What if $R(z)=1$?

Comment: It's a polynomial in $z$ of degree $s$

Comment: So s>0, I'm assuming

Comment: Yes, $s\ge p>0$ where $p$ is the order of the method. Zero-order methods just don't make any sense.

Comment: $\lim_{z \to \infty} |R(z)| = \infty$ for any non-constant polynomial $R$. In particular, $\lim_{y \to \infty} |R(-iy)| = \infty$ .

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: The question does  not say polynomial of degree $s$. What happened to 'at most' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming $s>0$, as $0$ order methods don't make sense as explained to me in the comments. Polynomials are entire (holomorphic on the complex plane). So by [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)), which states that a bounded entire complex function must be constant, $R(z)$ your polynomial must be unbounded on $\mathbb{C}$. To show it is unbounded on $\mathbb{C}^-$ you can first work with a monic polynomial and note it is unbounded on $\mathbb{C}^-$ by symmetry. To see this, suppose $z^m$ it is unbounded on just the right half plane. Then $(re^{i\theta})^m = r^m (\cos(m\theta)+i\sin(m\theta))$ is unbounded on the right half plane. Then reflecting across the imaginary axis yields $r^m(\cos(m\pi-m\theta)+i\sin(m\pi-m\theta))$ is also unbounded.

Since a polynomial $R$ of degree $s$ is such that $\lim_{|z|\to\infty} \frac{z^{s-1}}{R(z)}=0$ then $R(z)$ is unbounded, since $z^{s-1}$ is unbounded by the previous paragraph.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: The question does  not say polynomial of degree $s$. What happened to 'at most' ?

Comment: This is kind of a trivial distinction for this problem. All we needed was for R to have degree greater than 0. If you replace s by s' in the problem statement then let R have degree s the proof follows through unchanged

Answer (score 0):

But... $x^s$ is unbounded, isn't it ?

Comment: @MartinR: except for the case of $iz^s$, all polynomials have a real term $x^s$ along $x$, don't they ?